# Material UI TextField Custom Attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently trying to set a custom data attribute to a TextField component as such:

```
class TestTextField extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {console.log(this._input)}
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        label="Label 1"
        InputProps={{placeholder: 'Input 1', 'data-state': 'Data State 1'}}
        margin="normal"
        inputRef={(elem) => {this._input = elem}}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

However I can't get `data-state` to show up with the console log saying

```
 <textarea rows="1" class="MuiTextarea-textarea-67 MuiInput-input-56 MuiInput-inputMultiline-64" placeholder="Input 1" type="text">
```

Are custom attributes not supported for TextField? I am using v1.0.0-beta.6 (https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/text-field/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see custom props are [passed to the *FormControl* component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/TextField/TextField.js#L171). What you want [is probably `inputProps`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/TextField/TextField.js#L197) which is then [passed down to the actual `<input />`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/Input/Input.js#L546) (`InputComponent` is `"input"` by default)

Comment: I was like going crazy when i was not able to view the data attributes in markup, this post made it a piece of cake ..

Answer (score 20):

In case others didn't notice, @pier-paolo-ramon is saying to use the `inputProps` prop instead of the `InputProps` prop. Pay close attention to the case sensitivity.

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{placeholder: 'Input 1', 'data-state': 'Data State 1'}}
/>
```

Comment: works fine to me